# Replace all <a> with <span> tag in a string : Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all `<a>` with  `<span>` tag from a string .

code:

```
var a = input.replace(/<a>/g, "'<span>");
var b = a.replace(/<\/a>/g, "</span>");
var c = b.replace(/href/g, "title");
```

but it not worked for me and I could not add style as well

**Input :**  Angular is a platform for building mobile and desktop web applications.
`<a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a>` Achieve the maximum speed possible on the Web Platform today, and take it further, via Web Workers and server-side rendering.
  `<a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link Two</a>`

**Output :**  Angular is a platform for building mobile and desktop web applications.
`<span style="color:#0000EE" title="http://www.google.com">Test Link</span>` Achieve the maximum speed possible on the Web Platform today, and take it further, via Web Workers and server-side rendering.
  `<span style="color:#0000EE" title="http://www.google.com">Test Link Two</span>`.

can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: You are trying to replace the string "<a>", but there is no such string, because the link also has an href attribute. Regular expressions are not the right tool to tackle HTML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, regular expressions are not the right tool for tackling (i.e. parsing, modifying...) HTML. Here's an example demonstrating an approach using `DOMParser()` for actually replacing the link tags with a newly created span.

```js
var inputString = `Angular is a platform for building mobile and desktop web applications.
<a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a> Achieve the maximum speed possible on the Web Platform today, and take it further, via Web Workers and server-side rendering.
<a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link Two</a>`;

var domParser = new DOMParser();
var doc = domParser.parseFromString(inputString, 'text/html');
var links = doc.querySelectorAll('a:link');
links.forEach(function(linkTag) {
  var spanTag = document.createElement('span');
  spanTag.title = linkTag.href;
  spanTag.style.color = '#0000EE';
  spanTag.innerHTML = linkTag.innerHTML;
  linkTag.parentNode.replaceChild(spanTag, linkTag);
});
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: If the string has img tag that got affected while using this code , Is it possible to exclude image tag to be processed here @ConstantinGroß

Comment: The selector used in this code doesn't apply to img tags.